# Xamarin Deep Linking Issue

Tags: android, xamarin, deep-linking

I have set up a simple Xamarin app to try and use Deep Linking. The Deep Linking works perfectly when I use the IOS simulator. But I can't seem to get it to work for Android while debugging using an Android device.

I've set up my `MainActivity.cs` like so

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] {
        Intent.ActionView,
        Intent.CategoryDefault,
        Intent.CategoryBrowsable
    },
    DataScheme = "photocapture",
    DataHost = "PhotoCapture",
    DataPathPrefix = "/photocapture/")
]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        AndroidAppLinks.Init(this);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

Then in my `App.cs` I have an override for `OnAppLinkRequestReceived`

```
protected override async void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)
{ .... }
```

On the Android device I've download a HTML file with the following `href`

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Product 12345</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a href="photocapture://PhotoCapture.Views.PhotoCapturePage?id=123">Deeplink</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I click this link on the Android device the app is not opening up and the `OnAppLinkRequestReceived` is not catching in the debugger.

Also if I search the app name of the android device it does show up. The problem is just when clicking deep link from an external source.

Am I missing a step or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should refer [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/deep-link-content-with-xamarin-forms-url-navigation/) for more help.

Comment: Did you want to open your app in a webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link I was using that worked in IOS:

```
photocapture://PhotoCapture.Views.PhotoCapturePage?id=123
```

Did not work on android. I had to change `photocapture://` to `http://` to get it to work. So the final link looked like:

```
http://PhotoCapture.Views.PhotoCapturePage?id=123
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to enable Supported web addresses for xamarin android debug build in app settings.
appinfo->Set as default->supported web addresses

1. Enable Open supported links
2. add your domain in "supported web addresses" (ex: zxy.com)